# Selenium IDE - Array add values

Tags: selenium-ide

Let's say I have two String variables: `var1` and `var2`.

Is there any command on Selenium IDE (maybe `storeEval` with some javascript code), with which I can create an array and add the 2 variable values to it? Example:

```
var1 = "abc"

var2 = "def"

array = ("abc","def")
```

P.S: the array cannot have a fixed length. In this case I have just 2 variables, but in other scenarios I may have more than 10 variables, so I would need to create a loop and add all 10 variable values to the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple but isn't obvious

```
storeEval | ['one','two']          | array
storeEval | storedVars['array'][1] | second
echo      | ${second}
```

Or simpler but with much less safety

```
storeEval | ['one','two']                      | array
echo      | javascript{storedVars['array'][1]}
```

Adding new item dynamically

```
getEval | storedVars['array'].push('three')
```

You can make loop using selenium IDE flow control for example. Like:

```
storeEval | 0                                                | i
while     | storedVars['i']<storedVars['array'].length
echo      | javascript{storedVars['array'][storedVars['i']]}
storeEval | ${i}+1                                           | i 
endWhile
```

I hope it will help

Comment: storeEval does not work in newer Versions 
any solutions for this?